# Regarding variation of spectra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, banach-algebras

I have been reading the article [The variation of spectra by J.D Newburgh](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-18/issue-1/The-variation-of-spectra/10.1215/S0012-7094-51-01813-3.short). in this article and all related reference/ articles, the term 'variation of spectra' keeps coming in, but I nowhere find a formal definition of the term. Can anyone tell me its definition?

Answer (score 1):

According to the article

> "Newburgh, J. D. (1951). The variation of spectra. Duke Mathematical
> Journal, 18(1), 165–176. doi:10.1215/s0012-7094-51-01813-3"

The variation of spectra is the function $\sigma:A\rightarrow S$, where $A$ is a Banach algebra and $S$ is the metric space of compact subsets of complex plan, $\mathbb C$. The value of this function at point $x\in A$, is $\sigma(x)$, the spectrum of $x$.

Comment: So it is basically the set valued spectrum function that is upper semicontinuous. Am I right?

Comment: @user332905 if we consider the norm topology on $A$, the answer is "Yes".